# Inherit constructor of other contract inside an initialize function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, proxy-contracts, constructor

I'm trying to inherit the parentContract to the childContract, where the parentContract's constructor requires a parameter to be set, and the childContract is a proxy. Because the childContract is a proxy, setting the parentContract inside of the childContract's constructor like `constructor() parentContract(_param1) {}` won't work as it doesn't get called upon initialization. How can I use the functions of parentContract when using parameters in it's constructor and using the initialize() function?

```
contract parentContract {    
    constructor(address _param1) {
        param1 = _param1
    }

    function parentFunction() {
        ...
    }
}

contract childContract is Initializable, parentContract {   
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize() {
        admin = msg.sender
    }
}
```